# onclick event with requirejs

Tags: onclick, requirejs, axios

I'm using requirejs and have the following defined module:

**`loginView.js`**

```
define(['login'], (login) => {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/login') {
    const loginPage = `
      <form>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="password">
        <input type="button" onclick="${login.login()}" />
      </form>
    `
    document.getElementById('my-app').innerHTML = loginPage;;
  }
})
```

My login method is defined in a separate module:

**`loginHandler`**

```
define(['require', 'axios'], (require, axios) => {
  return {
    login: function() {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is that the login handler is being called immediately upon page load because I can see all of my `console.log` calls, which is not what I want.  I believe it has to do with `login.login()`, but setting it to just `login.login` renders the actual method in the page.

**How do I use an `onclick` event handler with requirejs?**

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to swap require with the login function.

```
const login = () => {
  require(['require', 'axios'], (require, axios) => {
    // do stuff
  })
}
```